# Creating "select all" button to select all buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a table that has multiple rows. I'm trying to select each row with a button; also, in the table heading, there's a select all button that will select ALL buttons in all rows. Here is the html:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="myController">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>
       <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="select-all" data-toggle="button" value="Show All" aria-pressed="false">
      </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody ng-repeat="company in fieldData">
    <tr>
     <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ company.address }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="select-one" data-toggle="button" value="Show" aria-pressed="false">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make a function using jQuery to change aria-pressed values of ALL rows? Any ideas?

Comment: Yes. Change #select-one buttons to aria-pressed="true" by pressing #select-all button.

Comment: Your using angular, will this be living in a directive?

Comment: The default value of those buttons are "false".

Comment: It will be in a controller

Comment: How about having a `scope` in `ng-repeat` like `aria-pressed="{{company.selected}}"`

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Sorry I'm pretty new to angular as well. Perhaps an example?

Comment: Perhaps add angularjs as a tag :)

Comment: See these links: [point 4](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make) and [here](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/ujmjbw5L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using Angular js.

I have write a simple code, have a look

```
<div>
<ul ng-controller="checkboxController">
    <li>Check All
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <label>{{item.Name}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.Selected" />
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
.controller("checkboxController", function checkboxController($scope) {
```

Angular code here

```
$scope.Items = [{
    Name: "Item one"
}, {
    Name: "Item two"
}, {
    Name: "Item three"
}];
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        item.Selected = $scope.selectedAll;
    });

};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

set an ng-model on the "Select All" checkbox then use the `ng-checked` directive to select/deselect all.

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="myController">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>
       <input type="button" ng-model="selectAll" class="btn btn-default" id="select-all" data-toggle="button" value="Show All" aria-pressed="false">
      </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody ng-repeat="company in fieldData">
    <tr>
     <td>{{ company.name }}</td>
     <td>{{ company.address }}</td>
     <td style="text-align: center">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="select-one" data-toggle="button" value="Show" aria-pressed="false" ng-checked="selectAll">
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```